# Keep the correlative number of a vectorized apply function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, vectorization, apply

With the data below I want to vectorize the following operations into an `apply` call, but when doing so I lose the correlative number of each of the vectorized operations.

The example data is as follow:

```
library(VGAM)
library(dplyr)

df<- structure(list(id_choice = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L,3L), V1 = c(-2.1578610393492, -7.99842015838894, -2.75141490020271,-10.4498142778112, -1.24287958770339, -0.378360296432904, -5.4054060545789,-1.91973213468639, -3.43124320737278), V2 = c(-0.707981236327309,-2.46810236795902, -0.929869936267716, -5.0157210007768, -0.602127441470801,-0.186681393158885, -2.06095189374723, -0.706069723181491, -1.04581628613078), V3 = c(-0.707981236327309, -2.46810236795902, -0.929869936267716,-3.34318115860932, -0.419902425557776, -0.141349098342894, -2.06095189374723,-0.706069723181491, -1.04581628613078)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), groups = structure(list(id_choice = 1:3, .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of","vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df","tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# id_choice      V1     V2     V3
# 1         1  -2.16  -0.708 -0.708
# 2         1  -8.00  -2.47  -2.47 
# 3         1  -2.75  -0.930 -0.930
# 4         2 -10.4   -5.02  -3.34 
# 5         2  -1.24  -0.602 -0.420
# 6         2  -0.378 -0.187 -0.141
# 7         3  -5.41  -2.06  -2.06 
# 8         3  -1.92  -0.706 -0.706
# 9         3  -3.43  -1.05  -1.05
```

I need to apply the same 2 operations to each V1, V2, and V3. Those are:

1. Generate `U <- V + Gumbel error`
2. Generate a Binary (`choice`) variable that takes a value of one at the maximum of `U` by `id_choice`

The extensive (and absolutely not appropriate) way to do it will be as follow (any improvements to point 2 of the current method are also very welcome). I will call it *The Dumb method*

## *The Dumb [but working] method*

```
# For V1...
# adding the random part to the error rgumbel
df$U1 <- df$V1 + rgumbel(nrow(df) , loc=0 , scale=1)  
# generating choice variable 
id_choice_split_1 <- with(df, split(U1,id_choice))
df$choice1 <- unlist(lapply(id_choice_split_1,
                            function(uValues)
                              as.numeric(uValues == max(uValues))))

# ...for V2...
# adding the random part to the error rgumbel
df$U2 <- df$V2 + rgumbel(nrow(df) , loc=0 , scale=1)  
# generating choice variable 
id_choice_split2 <- with(df, split(U2,id_choice))
df$choice2       <- unlist(lapply(id_choice_split2,
                                  function(uValues)
                                    as.numeric(uValues == max(uValues))))

# ...for V3.
# adding the random part to the error rgumbel
df$U3 <- df$V3 + rgumbel(nrow(df) , loc=0 , scale=1)  
# generating choice variable 
id_choice_split3 <- with(df, split(U3,id_choice))
df$choice3       <- unlist(lapply(id_choice_split3,
                                  function(uValues)
                                    as.numeric(uValues == max(uValues))))
```

Leading to....

```
# id_choice      V1     V2     V3     U1   choice1   U2   choice2   U3   choice3
# 1         1  -2.16  -0.708 -0.708 -2.89        0 -1.09        1 -1.42        0
# 2         1  -8.00  -2.47  -2.47  -8.94        0 -3.17        0 -2.15        0
# 3         1  -2.75  -0.930 -0.930 -2.51        1 -1.22        0 -0.130       1
# 4         2 -10.4   -5.02  -3.34  -8.87        0 -5.77        0 -2.82        0
# 5         2  -1.24  -0.602 -0.420  1.30        1 -0.477       0 -0.942       0
# 6         2  -0.378 -0.187 -0.141 -0.463       0  1.49        1 -0.121       1
# 7         3  -5.41  -2.06  -2.06  -4.28        0 -0.509       0 -1.31        0
# 8         3  -1.92  -0.706 -0.706 -0.633       1 -0.486       1  1.77        1
# 9         3  -3.43  -1.05  -1.05  -2.89        0 -1.68        0 -0.975       0
```

**Finally**, keeping just relevant variables (a.k.a: `id_choice` `choice1`, `choice2` and `choice3`).

This is my **desired output**

```
#keeping just relevant variables 
df<- data.frame(select(df,-c(U1,V1,
                                U2,V2,
                                U3,V3)))

#   id_choice choice1 choice2 choice3
# 1         1       0       1       0
# 2         1       0       0       0
# 3         1       1       0       1
# 4         2       0       0       0
# 5         2       1       0       0
# 6         2       0       1       1
# 7         3       0       0       0
# 8         3       1       1       1
# 9         3       0       0       0
```

Given that there are just repetitive operations I rather prefer to automatize them. Therefore, I created a functional that I invoke using `apply`:

## *The Smart [but not working yet] method*

```
choice_generator <- function(V){
  require(VGAM)
  V <- as.data.frame(V)
  # adding the random part to the error rgumbel
  U <- V + rgumbel(nrow(V) , loc=0 , scale=1)  
  # generating choice variable 
  id_choice_split <- with(df, split(U,id_choice))
  choice       <- unlist(lapply(id_choice_split,
                                function(uValues) as.numeric(uValues == max(uValues))))
  #keep it as data.frame
  choice <- data.frame(choice)
}

# getting a list with the choice variables
list_with_choices <-  apply(df[grep('V', names(df))] ,
                            MARGIN = 2,
                            FUN =choice_generator )

#generate_data_frame from the obtained list.
df$choices <- do.call("cbind", list_with_choices)
```

Leading to...

```
# id_choice      V1     V2     V3 choices$choice $choice $choice
# 1         1  -2.16  -0.708 -0.708              0       0       1
# 2         1  -8.00  -2.47  -2.47               0       0       0
# 3         1  -2.75  -0.930 -0.930              1       1       0
# 4         2 -10.4   -5.02  -3.34               0       0       0
# 5         2  -1.24  -0.602 -0.420              0       0       0
# 6         2  -0.378 -0.187 -0.141              1       1       1
# 7         3  -5.41  -2.06  -2.06               0       0       0
# 8         3  -1.92  -0.706 -0.706              1       1       0
# 9         3  -3.43  -1.05  -1.05               0       0       1

#New names:
#* choices.choice -> choices.choice...5
#* choices.choice -> choices.choice...6
#* choices.choice -> choices.choice...7


colnames(df)
#[1] "id_choice" "V1"        "V2"        "V3"        "choices"
```

As you can see, I lose **my desired output**, because the correlative number of `choice1`, `choice2`, and `choice3` that I was getting out of *The Dumb Method* is gone.

It is possible to keep the correlative number by a modification of my function? or another thing that I am missing? Thank you loads in advance for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Smart [but not working yet] method

One simple way to keep the name is to use `rlist::flatten()` before the call to cbind:

```
do.call("cbind", rlist::list.flatten(list_with_choices)) 
#      V1.choice V2.choice V3.choice
# [1,]         0         1         0
# [2,]         0         0         0
# [3,]         1         0         1
# ...
```

### A `dplyr` approach

I think it's one of these situations where `dplyr` shines: instead of `split`ting then `unlist`ing and so on, you can use a simple `group_by(id_choice)`, then apply a function on the individual Vx columns (that doesn't need to be aware of `df`):

```
choice_generator2 <- function(V){
  U <- V + rgumbel(length(V), 0, 1)
  1L * (U == max(U))
}

df %>%
  group_by(id_choice) %>%
  mutate(choice1 = choice_generator2(V1))
```

You can also apply it to all columns (replacing them in the process):

```
df %>%
  group_by(id_choice) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("V"), choice_generator2))
```

Or create new columns with the values:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id_choice) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("V"), choice_generator2, .names = "choice_{.col}"))
# A tibble: 9 x 7
# Groups:   id_choice [3]
#   id_choice      V1     V2     V3 choice_V1 choice_V2 choice_V3
#       <int>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <int>     <int>     <int>
# 1         1  -2.16  -0.708 -0.708         1         1         0
# 2         1  -8.00  -2.47  -2.47          0         0         1
# 3         1  -2.75  -0.930 -0.930         0         0         0
# 4         2 -10.4   -5.02  -3.34          0         0         0
# 5         2  -1.24  -0.602 -0.420         1         0         0
# 6         2  -0.378 -0.187 -0.141         0         1         1
# 7         3  -5.41  -2.06  -2.06          0         0         0
# 8         3  -1.92  -0.706 -0.706         1         0         1
# 9         3  -3.43  -1.05  -1.05          0         1         0
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your amazing answer @Alexlok, it was exactly what I was searching for. Additionally, I am very new to R, and each time that I wrote code I feel that there are tons of other more efficient/faster ways to do it and so many libraries that feel like an **entirely new universe** in itself. Therefore, most of the time, I try to stick to baseR as much as possible, but apparently, I am losing quite a few cool features. Is it `dplyr` the new *_unsaid golden standard_* or something like this? Would you recommend it for packaging also? Thank you again!

Comment: You can find plenty of discussions of this question online, but in brief yes: the `dplyr`/`tidyverse` approach makes life much easier for most standard analysis, and you should definitely learn it. I learned most of it by reading [r4ds](https://r4ds.had.co.nz). It is a bit more complicated to use in functions and packages, but nothing terrible. I would say it is now a pretty well-accepted "golden standard", just look at the other R Q/A here.